# Prevent sscanf from reading anything but a double in input file

Tags: c, parsing, scanf

I am trying to implement a parser. The input file has this form:

[Boundary1]

char* Boundary_type double Boundary_value;

[Boundary2]

etc...

In short this is how I do it:

```
fgets(buffer,128,my_file);
sscanf(buffer,"%[^ ] %lf;",bmarker_type,&value);
```

I want to stop the program if Boundary_value reads anything that's not a double, for example if there's an input mistake from the user.
I've tried reading Boundary_value as a `char*`, then using `strtod(str_value,NULL)` to convert it to a double. Problem is `strtod` returns 0.00000 if it's not possible, which is bad if the boundary value is actually 0, so I can't use that as a check.

Comment: *Problem is strtod returns 0.00000 if it's not possible* - this is truth, but not the whole truth. There are other ways of checking it's success Please read the `man` pages.

Comment: Don't try to use the `sscanf` for making a parser. [`strtod`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtod/) is much simpler. Read closely what the third parameter of `strtod` does.

Comment: If you really dare to use `sscanf()`, check its return value.

Comment: Consider this code:
`#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char* str = "0.15E+10A";
    char* fail_address = NULL;
    double dou = strtod(str,&fail_address);
    printf("Converted double: %lf\n",dou);
    printf("Bad character: %s\n",fail_address);
    return 0;
}`
Result is:
`Converted double: 1500000000.000000
Bad character: A`
Since ```strtod``` *always* returns a double value, the check should be on the variable fail_address, is this correct?

Comment: _If the subject sequence is empty or does not have the expected form, no conversion is
performed; the value of `nptr` is stored in the object pointed to by `endptr`, provided
that `endptr` is not a null pointer._